# node.js API call and churned nicely into a clean list

Tags: arrays, node.js, api

So im trying to get this [API](https://api.nicehash.com/api?method=stats.provider.workers&addr=3Hwm6i8aefzHhJTbEGtSJeR6tZCJXqY7EN) to print out into an array. It does.. but not all of the information. I've tried a few loops and I could not get it to behave the way I needed it to.  Any help would be appreciated

```
const request = require("request");

const url = "https://api.nicehash.com/api?method=stats.provider.workers&addr=3Hwm6i8aefzHhJTbEGtSJeR6tZCJXqY7EN";

request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
 let json = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

Edit: This is another attempt I've tried. However it returns a lot cleaner but still has all of the brackets, commas etc garbage. is there a way to clean that?

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://api.nicehash.com/api?method=stats.provider.workers&addr=3Hwm6i8aefzHhJTbEGtSJeR6tZCJXqY7EN';

request.get({
url: url,
json: true,
headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    }, (err, res, data) => {
     if (err) {
       console.log('Error:', err);
    } 
else if (res.statusCode !== 200) 
{
  console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
} 
else {(!err && data && data.result && data.result.workers)
     console.log(data.result.workers);
}
});
```

Comment: Please clarify what kind of result are you expecting and also add what you tried.

Comment: I got it working and have amended my original post. All i need to do now is filter out all the garbage like brackets and commas - thoughts?